# No bootable device on acer aspire 3

Tags: boot, laptop

My Acer aspire 3 laptop says no bootable device I've tried watching videos on YouTube to help solve this problem but I get stuck when I'm on boot tab on my screen it doesn't show boot mode it only shows secure boot and boot priority order...I've bought another hard drive tried it too but still it says no bootable device please assist

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is possible that the harddrive/SSD is no longer working. It is also possible that a BIOS setting got messed up. If the problem is a BIOS setting, you can restore the BIOS to default settings (aka factory defaults), then it should work with the original harddrive.

Comment: If you want to use the new harddrive you bought, you probably need to make "installation media" for Windows. Usually a usb-stick of sufficient size that you can use to install Windows on the new harddrive. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-installation-media-for-windows-99a58364-8c02-206f-aa6f-40c3b507420d

Comment: How did you get to that state? Was the machine working before? What was done to cuase that issue?